# How can i send ether to multiple address in one transaction by paying one transaction fee?

Tags: web3js, transactions, gas, ethereumjs

How can i send ether to multiple address in one transaction by paying one transaction fee. Like i want to publish multiple transaction at one go so i can incur only one transaction fee.

Comment: In a contract...

Comment: can it be done without smart contract ?

Comment: No, it cannot...

Comment: Using web3 batch also  require contract?

Comment: That wouldn't impose a single transaction though.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I send ether to multiple addresses in one transaction in order to pay transaction-fee once?

By aggregating several transfers in a contract constructor, and then deploying that contract.

For example:

```
pragma solidity 0.6.12;

contract Payer {
    constructor(address payable[] memory clients, uint256[] memory amounts) public payable {
        uint256 length = clients.length;
        require(length == amounts.length);

        // transfer the required amount of ether to each one of the clients
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < length; i++)
            clients[i].transfer(amounts[i]);

        // in case you deployed the contract with more ether than required,
        // transfer the remaining ether back to yourself
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The fee you pay when sending ether to multiple transactions is about the same you'd pay if you sent them separately. The gas calculations are pretty much the same if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way: https://cointool.app

Harder way:

Source code: https://github.com/rstormsf/multisender/blob/master/contracts/contracts/multisender/UpgradebleStormSender.sol

```
function multisendToken(address token, address[] _contributors, uint256[] _balances) public hasFee payable {
uint256 total = 0;
require(_contributors.length <= arrayLimit());
ERC20 erc20token = ERC20(token);
uint8 i = 0;
for (i; i < _contributors.length; i++) {
    erc20token.transferFrom(msg.sender, _contributors[i], _balances[i]);
    total += _balances[i];
}
setTxCount(msg.sender, txCount(msg.sender).add(1));
Multisended(total, token);
```

}